# How can I access related models of a model instance in Loopback Android

Tags: android, model, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a loopback model *customer* and I wanted to access the related model *order*, from a customer model instance in android. But, I couldn't find any documentation regarding this. Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

```
{
  "name": "customer",
  "plural": "customers",
  "base": "User",
  "properties": {
    "phoneVerified": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": "false"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "roles": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Role",
      "through": "RoleMapping",
      "foreignKey": "principalId"
    },
    "baggedProducts": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "product",
      "through": "baggedProduct",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    },
    "orders": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "order",
      "foreignKey": "orderId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the given relation, model **customer** has many model **order**. Therefore, to access orders from a given customer use:

```
customer.order.find({}, function(err, results) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
});
```

Now if you are using URL to fetch results: you need to find the url for this method which will be like this:

```
{your server}/customer/{id}/orders
```

Else if you are using Android SDK, follow this: [Android SDK guide for LoopBack](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Android+SDK).